# Don't want "Safely Remove Hardware" procedure under Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I am using a PC with Windows XP and a laptop with Windows 7.

Under Windows 7, I can simply physically remove any USB stick. Files are written directly, when this is finished I just pull out the USB stick.

Under Windows XP, I have to "Safely Remove Hardware" and go through a complicated procedure where it's easy to make errors.

Can I set Windows XP so that it behaves like Windows 7 with respect to removal of USB sticks? I.e. I do not want to go through the annoying "Safely Remove Hardware" procedure under Win XP,. I rather would like the files to be written directly and then just pull out the USB stick? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~life is too short to Safely remove USB drives ^^

In the Device manager when you go under your disk proprieties there is a couple of settings for the removal policy where you can choose from:

- Improve for performance. or,
- for quick removal

choose the second one since it takes into consideration quick-removal without going through that complicated procedure and with no harm to your USB stick and just ignore that notification message.

Comment: just dont ignore any writes that you started and forgot about :-)